# sed match the 2nd occurrence of the pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed

```
$Subj .= "HAD PROBLEMS";

if ($To) {
    $Cc = "abc\@xyz.com";
}
else {
    $Cc = "abc\@xyz.com";
}
```

I have the above text in a file. I need to replace the email id in $Cc with a new email id.

I have the following sed command to do so.

```
sed '\|HAD PROBLEMS|,/}/ s/$Cc = (\"[A-Za-z0-9])(.)([A-Za-z0-9]*)\@xyz.com\"/\$Cc = "new email\@xyz.com"/' test.txt
```

This command will replace the email id only for the $Cc variable in the if {} block (first occurrence of $Cc) since my ending match pattern is a '}'. I want to replace email id in the second $Cc as well. how do i match on the 2nd occurrence of '}' ?

Comment: Is this the _only_ text in the file?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace the Cc address to new email address, then try the below

```
$ sed 's/\$Cc.*/\$Cc="new_mail\@abc.com"/g' input.txt
$Subj .= "HAD PROBLEMS";

if ($To) {
    $Cc="new_mail@abc.com"
}
else {
    $Cc="new_mail@abc.com"
}
```

Comment: I wonder if the `@` in the new address should be escaped, as it is in the old one? And the `g` modifier on the `s` sed command is not needed, IMHO.